# Changing color of the row that has been selected by longclick in ListView Android

Tags: android, listview

I want to highlight the selected row on my `ListView` when it's long pressed. Now I'm able to do that when the row just clicked as in photo:

[image: selected row.jpg]

How can I do this with long click?
My `setOnItemLongClickListener` function so far:

```
user_data.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
           selected_note = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
           user_data.setItemChecked(i,true);
           return  true;
      }
});
```

Comment: try `view.setBackgroundColor((#00ff00)`

Comment: Mike I appreciate your fast answer but that doesn't work. You get what I want to do right?

Comment: Not entirely as it depends upon exactly what you want to change, which could/would depend upon what the layout contains. It might be best to include the xml for the layout. I took that snippet from a ListView where I set alternating background colors (within the getView() method of the adpater).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Then this might help

In your list view layout

```
android:background="@drawable/key"
```

Create key.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item 
android:state_selected="true"
android:drawable="@color/pressed_color"/>
<item
android:drawable="@color/default_color" />
</selector>
```

Add this to your listview onClickListener:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long arg3) {
        view.setSelected(true);
        //your logic what you want to do
    }
});
```

Define diff colors in res/values/colors.xml

And define colors in colors.xml as resources "pressed_color" or relesed color

Comment: Quamran thanks but can you tell me what to write my java class to use that drawable.xml

Comment: That's great explanation it works. Thanks a lot Qamran.

Comment: @AhmetUrun If it helped dont forget to give it vote up.